# optimization in R by changing values within a vector

Tags: r, loops, optimization, constraints

i am very new to R, and want to use R to solve for a simple question.

i am trying to optimize probability weighted consumption with the end balance to be zero. the initial amount is `1`. can anyone help? i got some initial code trying to use optim, but not successful.

```
ret <- rnorm(n = 4)
prob <- seq(0.9,0.4,by = 0.1)
money <- rep(NA,4)


consumption <- function(consumption){
    consumption[3] <- 1 - (consumption[1]+consumption[2])
    money[1] <- 1
    for (i in 2:4){
        money[i] <- (money[i-1] - consumption[i-1])*(1+ret[i])
    }
    #we have to make sure money[4] = 0, i don't know where to put this.
    money[4] = 0
    return(-consumption%*%t(prob))
}
optim(consumption,c(0.1,0.1,0.8))
```

Comment: Any helps? The challenge is Money[3] needs to be zero. This constraint is not easy to add into current solvers available. Thanks.

Comment: the problem might be the multiplication part `-con%*%prob)`, what is your desired output? `%*%` is for matrix multiplication

Comment: The output of the `consumption` function does not depend on its input and there are errors in accessing variables beyond their length.

Comment: @timfaber that's the desired output. It's the sum of those two vectors. Using that formula works well for the purpose.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck it does depend. Because those consumption link to each other to make the end balance to be zero for money.

Comment: anyone help? I will keep update it until have answers.

Comment: The sum of both vectors or the matrix product? If you want the matrix product I can only make it work by using `-consumption%*%t(prob)`. Furthermore, your loop does not include the full vector length like this `(i in 2:(n+1))` . You can simply add `money[4] = 0` after the for loop (before return). The problem is with the optim input however.

Comment: You may have intended dependence but the code in the question did not show such dependence.  It seems you have since edited it but there are still problems with the function.The `optim` call shown will try to pass a vector of length 3 to `consumption` and so in the last line of consumption it tries to multiply a vector of length 3 with a vector of length 10.  Also 2:n+1 computes 2:n and then adds 1 to each element of that vector.

Comment: @timfaber i tried to add money[4]=0 but not working. I edited the codes

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks. I changed n to numbers.  I think still how to have a constraint is not clear for me.

Comment: What is the point of computing `money`?  The return value does not depend on it.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck money left at year 4 is zero. It is an outcome (constraint) of consumptions. You basically have to spend all your money in 3 years. With probability for each year as weights.

Comment: The point is that your function computes it and then ignores it.  Had you not computed it the result of the function would be the same so it is pointless.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks for the help. Do you know how to modify the function to incorporate that?

Comment: You can add a penalty to the objective functions which penalizes deviations the constraint or you can look for a constrained optimization function.. Google for CRAN Optimization Task View.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thanks. The task view has too many options and I've been there. I will search more.

Comment: I am still not able to figure out how to construct a constraint function. This is simple with three years, in longer time there is no way I can write functions using consumption vectors. It is surprising very easy in Excel. But i am still hoping someone can help write it right in R

Comment: still unsolved....